# Timeout expired, optimize query

Tags: c#, sql-server, query-optimization

I have this query to get all detail of Bills between two dates:

```
SELECT DT.* 
FROM DetailTable DT, BillTable BT, PackageTable PT
WHERE PT.Id = BT.IdPackage 
  AND DT.IdBill= BT.Id 
  AND PT.CodeCompany = @codeCompany
  AND PT.Date BETWEEN @begin and @end
```

For every package there are many bills, and I want to get the details of bills of a company,
the result in database it just 20,000 but I have :

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The
>   timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the
>   server is not responding.

the c# code :

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(SqlServerMasterConnection))
{
  if (sqlConn.State != ConnectionState.Open) sqlConn.Open();
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DT.* from DetailTable DT, BillTable BT, PackageTable PT where  PT.Id= BT.IdPackage and DT.IdBill= BT.Id and  PT.CodeCompany = @codeCompany and PT.Date between @begin and @end",
                            sqlConn))
  {
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter(@begin , beginDate));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@end", endDate));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@codeCompany", codeCompany));
    using (DbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
           //work todo
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I even tried this in SQL Server Management it take 25 seconds! any hint please to fix that.

**Update**

This is the execution plan :

[image]

**Update2**

There's two problems that I thing for this problem (I want your ideas).

1. `PT.Date` is a `char(8)` (it was used by the developer how begin this project) (yyyyMMdd)
2. the `detailTable` contain 102 columns.

Comment: Use proper joins. This is 2013

Comment: Please add your execution plan. Maybe you just need to add some indexes on your tables.

Comment: @Devart, added the execution plan, and i use the Id as a primary key autoincrement, and the relation with the Foreign key

Comment: Please tell, you need get data from all columns in `DetailTable`? If no, add the non-clustered index with included columns.

Comment: @Devart, yes I have to get all columns

Comment: Can you provide the columns + datatypes(length). Do you have `[N]VARCHAR(MAX)` columns?

Comment: @Devart, i update my question, and the table don't have VARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: 102.... Sadly. This is one way to increase performance - normalize `DetailTable`. And change data-type for `PT.Date` (`DATE` or `DATETIME`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT DT.*
FROM dbo.DetailTable DT
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.BillTable BT
    JOIN (
        SELECT PT.Id
        FROM dbo.PackageTable PT
        WHERE PT.CodeCompany = @codeCompany
            AND PT.Date BETWEEN @begin AND @end 
    ) PT ON PT.Id = BT.IdPackage
    WHERE DT.IdBill = BT.Id 
)
```

Another way -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Test1
      @codeCompany VARCHAR(50)
    , @begin DATETIME
    , @end DATETIME
AS
BEGIN

    IF OBJECT_ID (N'tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp

    CREATE TABLE #temp (ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY)

    INSERT INTO #temp (ID)
    SELECT BT.Id
    FROM dbo.BillTable BT
    JOIN dbo.PackageTable PT ON PT.Id = BT.IdPackage
    WHERE PT.CodeCompany = @codeCompany
    AND PT.[Date] BETWEEN @begin AND @end 

    SELECT DT.*
    FROM dbo.DetailTable DT
    WHERE DT.IdBill IN (SELECT Id FROM #temp)

END
```

Comment: for the first one the same result (24 sec), but with the PROCEDURE is only 7 sec, I want to not use it, i will let it as my last solution, (thx for your answers)