# sql server strange behavior (query time respond)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I already asked a question ["Timeout expired, optimize query"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485530/timeout-expired-optimize-query#comment27176073_18485530) with problem for a time to respond sql server for my query :

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(SqlServerMasterConnection))
{
  if (sqlConn.State != ConnectionState.Open) sqlConn.Open();
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DT.* from DetailTable DT, BillTable BT, PackageTable PT
                                         where  PT.Id= BT.IdPackage and DT.IdBill= BT.Id 
                                         and  PT.CodeCompany = @codeCompany and PT.Date between @begin and @end",
                                         sqlConn))
 {
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@begin , beginDate));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@end", endDate));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@codeCompany", codeCompany));
    using (DbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
       while (reader.Read())
       {
          //work todo
       }
    }
 }
}
```

it take 28 sec for 20,000 record,

the strange behavior that I wrote this

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(SqlServerMasterConnection))
{
  if (sqlConn.State != ConnectionState.Open) sqlConn.Open();
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DT.* from DetailTable DT, BillTable BT, PackageTable PT where  PT.Id= BT.IdPackage and DT.IdBill= BT.Id 
                                         and  PT.CodeCompany = @codeCompany and PT.Date between '" + beginDate + "' and '" + endDate + "'"
                                         ,sqlConn))
 {
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@codeCompany", codeCompany));
    using (DbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
       while (reader.Read())
       {
          //work todo
       }
    }
 }
}
```

I changed `@date` with the sent value without `SqlParameter` and I got the result in 0 sec !!

any suggestion for this result

**PS :**

- we save the date in the DataBase as string YYYYMMDD (PT.Date is a varchar(8))
- beginDate  and enddate are string like (20130904)

Comment: What's the type of `beginDate`?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic, begindate and enddate is string value YYYYMMDD

Comment: on this line `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@begin , beginDate));` you're missing quotes around @begin, is that a typo?

Comment: @Tanner, the type of value in data base is a strng and I send a string value, then I have to add a quotes in sqlParametre !

Comment: In your first code sample you have: `@begin` which should be `"@begin"` with quotes around the name of the parameter, was just checking if this was a typo?

Answer (score 0):

If your query isn't changing in structure and you're executing it with the same parameters then perhaps SQL Server is caching the results of your query, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826784/does-sql-server-caches-query-results) for a similar issue.